# RxCpp: how to control subject observer's lifetime when used with buffer_with_time

Tags: c++, reactive-programming

The purpose of the following code is to have various classes publish data to an observable.  Some classes will observe every data, some will observe periodically with buffer_with_time().

This works well until the program exits, then it crashes, probably because the observer using buffer_with_time() is still hanging on to some thread.

```
struct Data
{
    Data() : _subscriber(_subject.get_subscriber()) { }
    ~Data()  { _subscriber.on_completed(); }

    void publish(std::string data) { _subscriber.on_next(data); }
    rxcpp::observable<std::string> observable() { return _subject.get_observable(); }

private:
    rxcpp::subjects::subject<std::string> _subject;
    rxcpp::subscriber<std::string> _subscriber;
};

void foo()
{
    Data data;

    auto period = std::chrono::milliseconds(30);
    auto s1 = data.observable()
        .buffer_with_time(period , rxcpp::observe_on_new_thread())
        .subscribe([](std::vector<std::string>& data) 
           { std::cout << data.size() << std::endl; });

    data.publish("test 1");
    data.publish("test 2");
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));

    // hope to call something here so s1's thread can be joined.
    // program crashes upon exit
}
```

I tried calling "s1.unsubscribe()", and various as_blocking(), from(), merge(), but still can't get the program to exit gracefully.

Note that I used "subjects" here because "publish" can then be called from different places (which can be from different threads). I am not sure if this is the best mechanism to do that, I am open to other ways to accomplish that.

Advice?

Comment: I am able to get the program to work by replacing rxcpp::observe_on_newThread(0 with rxcpp::observe_on_one_worker(rxcpp::observe_on_new_thread().create_coordinator().get_scheduler())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very close to working..

However, having the Data destructor complete the input while also wanting the subscription to block the exit of foo until input is completed makes this more complex.

Here is a way to ensure that foo blocks after Data destructs. This is using the existing Data contract.

```
void foo1()
{
    rxcpp::observable<std::vector<std::string>> buffered;
    {
        Data data;

        auto period = std::chrono::milliseconds(30);
        buffered = data.observable()
            .buffer_with_time(period , rxcpp::observe_on_new_thread())
            .publish().ref_count();

        buffered
            .subscribe([](const std::vector<std::string>& data)
               { printf("%lu\n", data.size()); },
               [](){printf("data complete\n");});

        data.publish("test 1");
        data.publish("test 2");

        // hope to call something here so s1's thread can be joined.
        // program crashes upon exit
    }
    buffered.as_blocking().subscribe();

    printf("exit foo1\n");
}
```

Alternatively, the changing the shape of Data (add a complete method) would allow the following code:

```
struct Data
{
    Data() : _subscriber(_subject.get_subscriber()) { }
    ~Data()  { complete(); }

    void publish(std::string data) { _subscriber.on_next(data); }
    void complete() {_subscriber.on_completed();}
    rxcpp::observable<std::string> observable() { return _subject.get_observable(); }

private:
    rxcpp::subjects::subject<std::string> _subject;
    rxcpp::subscriber<std::string> _subscriber;
};

void foo2()
{
    printf("foo2\n");

    Data data;

    auto newthread = rxcpp::observe_on_new_thread();

    auto period = std::chrono::milliseconds(30);
    auto buffered = data.observable()
        .buffer_with_time(period , newthread)
        .tap([](const std::vector<std::string>& data)
           { printf("%lu\n", data.size()); },
           [](){printf("data complete\n");});

    auto emitter = rxcpp::sources::timer(std::chrono::milliseconds(0), newthread)
        .tap([&](long) {
            data.publish("test 1");
            data.publish("test 2");
            data.complete();
        });

    // hope to call something here so s1's thread can be joined.
    // program crashes upon exit
    buffered.combine_latest(newthread, emitter).as_blocking().subscribe();

    printf("exit foo2\n");
}
```

I think that this better expresses the dependencies..

Comment: I tried the suggestion in foo1() - the program still crashes after printing out "exit foo1".  I don't think my program logic can use foo2() - because data.publish() will be called from different functions and it will be logically difficult to put it in an emitter.  However, although I have no idea why, but I use rxcpp::observe_on_one_worker(rxcpp::observe_on_new_thread().create_coordinator().get_scheduler()) instead of rxcpp::observe_on_new_thread() in foo1(), then the program totally works.

Comment: Hmmm.  What platform does the crash occur on?

Comment: Also, does foo1 crash or are you taking the idea expressed in foo1 and using it in different code?  Using observe_on_one_worker just means that a single thread is shared across all active subscriptions that use it. If your code is different than foo1 called by a main, then perhaps there is an issue in the code I have not seen. For instance, if publish on the same instance of Data is called from more than one thread that would cause undefined behavior.

Comment: Windows 7, VS 2013, using Google test framework running exactly foo1() (renamed to TEST(Rxcpp, Foo) for Google test's sake).

Comment: I did make one change in foo1() - added the Data::complete() function like you suggested, and calling data.complete() prior to buffered.as_blocking().subscribe();  Therefore I won't need the scoping to destroy Data.  The program still crashes as if buffered.as_blocking().subscribe() has no effect.

Comment: The crash appears to occur in a thread in rx-buffer_time.hpp line 105: localState->dest.on_next(std::move(localState->chunks.front()));  The debugger shows localState->chunks has a size 0.  The assertion is: Expression: deque iterator not dereferencable

Comment: Sorry, I have been sick.. Just tried this on Windows using VC2015 and the latest rxcpp on github. I am unable to repro this crash. Looking at line 105 - it seems that could happen if produce was run after on_complete. I could add an if statement before 105 if(localState->chunks.size() == 0) return;

Comment: Downloaded your latest rxcpp from GitHub.  It's crashing on a different point.  I wouldn't have noticed it if I didn't set a breakpoint on the abort function.  I think your suggestion that the buffered.as_blocking().subscribe() maybe causing some kind of access to the thread after on_complete may be right.  I changed rx-newthread.hpp line 85 to just return instead of abort().  Then everything works.  But I don't know if I am just putting a band-aid on things.  Can keepAlive->q be legitimately empty?  In any case, thanks so much for your time.